# How to init an array of contours using memstorage

Tags: c#, emgucv

I want to init an array of contours. The foliwing works so far:

```
Contour<Point> control_shapes1 = new Contour<Point>(new MemStorage());
Contour<Point>[] control_shapes = new Contour<Point>[13];
```

but this don't work:

```
Contour<Point>[] control_shapes = new Contour<Point>(new MemStorage())[13];
```

nether this:

```
Contour<Point>[] control_shapes = new Contour<Point>[13](new MemStorage());
```

(I should mention that all this is done in the global area for the first try. Later i will try to do it better, but for the moment ...)

How is the initialization done correctly ?

or is this impossible ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more concise version using LINQ

```
Contour<Point>[] control_shapes = Enumerable.Range(0, 13).Select(i => new Contour<Point>(new MemStorage())).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works so far for the init-part. Unfortunately i get an new error: (i have the german version) Something about that i've tryed to read/write in secured memory. (Es wurde versucht, im geschützten Speicher zu lesen oder zu schreiben. Dies ist häufig ein Hinweis darauf, dass anderer Speicher beschädigt ist.) Is there something i have to take care if i fill the contoures ?

Comment: @user4117521 I'm not familiar with `emgu`. I was following your code for how to instantiate a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing an `array` means you allocate space on the heap to store your data. It will have its default value set after initializing, so you will still have to fill it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < control_shapes.Length; i++)
{
    control_shapes[i] = new Contour<Point>(new MemStorage());
}
```

That is the correct way to initialize the array.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601(v=vs.71).aspx):

> Array members are automatically initialized to the default initial value for the array type if the array is not initialized at the time it is declared. If the array declaration is a field of a type, then when the type is instantiated, the array will be set to its default value of null.

Comment: Thank you too for your solution. But the same error like mentioned above appears. But at least i'm a step closer :P

Comment: My answer is the same as @Rotem's; I am not familiar with Emgu either. Try to Google the error, it might help you. If not, you could always ask a new question, though make sure to provide your research if you do that. Good luck!